# cURL ports not open - any viable alternative?

Tags: curl, port, shared-hosting

I have a client hosted with GoDaddy - but they're quite restrictive with their service and don't allow very many ports to be open.

I have a script that needs to communicate on an arbitrary port (1129) via cURL but of course GoDaddy won't have any of it. Is there any alternative that I can implement to still confer with the target source on port 1129 but bypass the need (at least on the server's end) to use port 1129?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an [SSH tunnel](http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/ssh-tunnel.html).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use sockets but on the other hand GoDaddy may not allow that also. Changing the hosting company might be the only solution.